# textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: isn't called when inputing in a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` and I want it has a maximum text length of 20. So I let self(the current view controller) agree to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and set self as the text field's delegate, and use the following method to set a maximum length:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.nickNameTextField)
    {
        if (textField.text.length > 20)
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

However when I insert a breakpoint in this function I found that this function wasn't called when I typed in any words, much less when the text's length exceeds 20. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Check if the delegate has been set up properly for `UITextField`. Also I would suggest you to use tag instead of name.

Comment: @ManjulShrestha yeah I've set the textfield' delegate in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: How you instantiate your text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've figured out the problem. I use this grammar to instantiate a UITextField:

```
self.nickNameTextField.delegate = self;
self.nickNameTextField = ({
    UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
    textField.placeholder = [BBTCurrentUserManager sharedCurrentUserManager].currentUser.nickName;
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    textField;
});
```

Originally I set the textField's delegate outside the braces(like the code above). But when I move `self.nickNameTextField.delegate = self;`inside the braces then it worked. However I have no idea about why this happened, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't linked your textfield with the delegate
Right click on textField which you want to have delegated and drag the textField on the viewcontroller and drop to select the delegate.

Comment: Well I created the textfield programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I show you steps and screenshot for connecting textField and delegate with XIB or Storyboard.

In storyboard

STEP 1: Click the TextField
[image]

STEP 2: Drag the TextField to ViewController
[image]

STEP 3: Click "control+mouse" on TextField to ViewController.h and line shows[image]

STEP 4:Now Box will appear and give the TextField Name[image]

STEP 5:Right Click the TextField in ViewController
[image]

STEP 6:Hook Up the Delegate to ViewController
[image]

If you want to programmatically create the textField

```
UITextField *txtfldMaxLength = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 250, 50)];
txtfldMaxLength.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtfldMaxLength.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtfldMaxLength.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtfldMaxLength.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
txtfldMaxLength.placeholder = @"enter something";
txtfldMaxLength.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtfldMaxLength.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtfldMaxLength.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtfldMaxLength.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtfldMaxLength.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtfldMaxLength.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:txtfldMaxLength];
```